Error code 9, message: Cannot modify allocated ranges in CreateConnection. Please use UpdateConnection
I'm having issues deploying SQL DB instance on GCP.
I was getting the below error: 
Error: Error waiting for Create Service Networking Connection: Error code 9, message: Cannot modify allocated ranges in CreateConnection. Please use UpdateConnection.
Code:
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
  name = "edddddddd-one-vpc"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "public_subnet" {
  name = "edddddddd-public-one-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.0.0.0/24"
  region = var.region
  network = google_compute_network.vpc.self_link
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "private_subnet" {
  name = "edddddddd-private-one-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.1.0.0/24"
  region = var.region
  network = google_compute_network.vpc.self_link
  purpose = "PRIVATE_SERVICE_CONNECT"
  private_ip_google_access = true
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_service_access" {
  name = "edddddddd-private-service-access"
  purpose = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 24
  network = google_compute_network.vpc.name
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_vpc_connection" {
  network = google_compute_network.vpc.self_link
  service = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private_service_access.name]
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "database" {
  for_each = toset([
    "serv1",
    "serv2",
    "serv3",
  ])

  name = "${each.key}-one-mysql-db"
  region           = var.region
  database_version = "MYSQL_8_0"
  depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection]
  settings {
    tier = "db-n1-standard-2"
    edition = "ENTERPRISE"
    availability_type = "ZONAL"
    location_preference {
      zone = var.zone
    }
    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled = false
      private_network = "projects/${var.gcp_project}/global/networks/${google_compute_subnetwork.private_subnet.name}"
      enable_private_path_for_google_cloud_services = false
    }
  }
}



Add 'update_on_creation_fail = true' to 'google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection'

there is no such parameter in the docs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/5.34.0/docs/resources/service_networking_connection

There is in later versions: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/6.6.0/docs/resources/service_networking_connection

Chris' comment is correct and should be an answer...

Add update_on_creation_fail = true to google_service_networking_connection...

